# Getting DataRow value from cell clicked (RadGridView)

Tags: c#, wpf, database, gridview, radgridview

So i tried to get row value from my RadGridView and use the `SelectionChanged` like this:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    var a = dataGrid.SelectedItem.ToString();
    MessageBox.Show(a);
}
```

I think i will get the cell value if i click it. But the output from `a` is System.Data.DataRow for everything (cells) i clicked on the table. How is exactly i can get the DataRow value?

edit : How can i get all Row values after i click any cells?

Comment: What the type of instance you bind to youy bind to your RadGridView ? How do you set the data source of your grid ?

Comment: @CodeNotFound in the xaml like this `<telerik:GridViewDataColumn DataMemberBinding="{Binding value}" />` for everycolumn, and `dataGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0];` thats from the code behind. actually im new here in this wpf

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to cast it to a `DataRow`, then you can use it's methods, f.e. `Field`:

```
private void dataGrid_SelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangeEventArgs e)
{
    DataRow row = (DataRow) dataGrid.SelectedItem;
    string name = row.Field<string>("Name"); 
    MessageBox.Show(name);
}
```

This presumes that there is a column `Name`, but i'm sure you'll understand it.

If you want to output all column values(f.e. for debugging purposes) you can use:

```
string allValues = String.Join(", ", row.ItemArray);
```

Comment: nvm i get it why i got the error before thanks anyway but what if i want to get all row (if i click any cell) i editted my question for that. by the way not all my data is string, 1 column is int.

Comment: @Mirza: it was just an example. Of course you have to use the appropriate type for the generic `Field`-extension method. So for example: `int id = row.Field<int>("ID");`. You could also use string for all: `string value = row["columnname"].ToString();`. But i would prefer the correct type instead.

Comment: @Mirza: acc. to your updated question, what is the desired result, what means "How can i get all Row values after i click any cells"? I have shown you already an example how to get all values as a single string. You can use `DataRow.Field<type>(index or name)` or `row[index or name]` to get values of each column.

Comment: @TimSchmelter so I deleted my answer. :)

Comment: for my updated question if i click any row, the result will be string showing all row from column1,column2 and so. if i got id and name column, if i click any row and the outpull will be "id1 name1" something like that and not all column is string. How can i do that? ty

Comment: I still don't understand the challenge. You don't know the columns and their types or you always want string even if it is something different? If that's the case you could simply use `string c1=row[0].ToString();string c2=row[1].ToString(); ...`

Comment: the purpose for my editted question is, i want the result to be in textbox, so maybe the id1 will be in textbox1, and name1 will be in textbox2. is that possible? @TimSchmelter

Comment: @Mirza: Sure: `textbox1.Text=row["id"].ToString();textbox2.Text=row["name"].ToString();`. Instead of `ToString` you can also use the `Field`: `textbox1.Text=row.Field<int>("id").ToString()`

Answer (score 0):

use select() method

DataRow[] foundRows = YourDataTable.Select(searchExpression);